# How to convert a long String of numbers into number type in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am converting a long Sting of numbers values to number data type with `Number()` and `parseInt()` method of js but it is returning a hexadecimal value.
Does anybody know how to convert a long string values of number to Number data type?

```
// "1245458787546574878756756754561464567867"(type:String) to 1245458787546574878756756754561464567867 (type:Number)

var str = "1245458787546574878756756754561464567867";
console.log(Number(str)); //1.2454587875465749e+39
console.log(parseInt(str)); //1.2454587875465749e+39
console.log(parseInt(str,10)); //1.2454587875465749e+39
console.log(str.length); //40
```

Comment: It's not hexadecimal value but decimal expressed in exponential form. It is a number.

Comment: what is actually the problem? the numer is too long to be converted to 64 bit float. the first with `Number` shound work, as with an unary plus. the other ones change the numbera to integera and should work with a given integer number as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz I simply want to convert the data type String to Number and values will remain same don't want it to be converted to 64 bit float

Comment: the number type in javascript is 64 bit float.

Comment: If you are requesting a reopen on the question, can you explain why your question is not answered in the referenced questions?